# Need help troubleshooting: React WYSIWYG editor dropdowns closing immediately after opening

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg, react-draft-wysiwyg

Using React WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) rich text editor, I am able to create an editor box, but I'm having a bug where the dropdowns close immediately after opening. I have not specially added any event listeners and I'm not sure what is causing this.

When I add a "Break On" using the dev tools, I see that the dropdown opens and is immediately closed after.

I would appreciate any advice in tackling this as I don't seem to make any progress on this bug so far [image: view with dev tools enabled]

I've tried turning off some even listeners using the dev tools. This hasn't achieved anything, but even if it had, I'm not sure what would be the use anyways.

I've removed all other functionality from the page that the Editor is on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.